# Инициализация двух классов

Tags: java

Как правильно провести инициализацию в конструкторе класса Solution.C?

```
class Solution{

    class A(B b){

        private B b;

        A(){

            this.b=b;
        }
    }

    class B{

        private A a;

        B(A a){

            this.a=a;
        }
    }

    class C{

        C(){

            A a=new //...
            B b=new //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не стоит так делать. Наличие в коде циклических зависимостей — верный признак неверной архитектуры и явный симптом для рефакторинга.

Comment: Невозможно рассуждать «правильно/неправильно» в отрыве от семантики классов. А о семантике невозможно рассуждать с именами `A`, `B`, `C`. Дайте настоящую семантику, настоящие названия классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо, чтобы классы A и B хранили ссылки друг на друга, то можно передавать эти ссылки не в качестве аргументов в конструкторы, а в качестве значений соответствующих свойств, т.е.

```
class A{
private B b;

A(){
//код конструктора
}

public void setB(B b){
this.b = b;
}
}

public B getB(){
return b;
}
```

и точно также и для класса B.

для класса C:

```
public class C{
C(){
A a = new A(new B());
B b = a.getB();
}
```